# How to get select query working sqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to perform a select query on my users table with sqli in php.
For security reasons (sql injection) i want to do it using parameter(s).
Also i want to store the result in a php variable.

This is my code:

the `$conn` variable is filled in correctly.

```
$login = $_POST['username'];

//Check if username is available
/*Line44*/ $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT login FROM users WHERE login = ?");
/*Line45*/ $stmt->bind_param('s', $login);
           $result = $stmt->execute();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    echo "This username is in use.";
}
else
{    
    //Add account to database
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (login, password, email, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $login, $md5pass, $email, $gender);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    echo "<font color=\"#254117;\">Your account is succesfully geregistered! <br />U can now login!</font>";
}
```

I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cammerta\registreer.php on line 44
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\cammerta\registreer.php on line 45

I hope someone can provide an solution and explain to me what i did wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
$stmt->execute();
```

Plus

1.Please run query in phpmyadmin or any program

2.Maybe you not set variables. $login, $md5pass, $email, $gender

Comment: Thanks 4 your anwser. I got my code from the same website you got your example. all have set my variables correctly. I want to store my result in a variable so i can check if the are rows in it.

Comment: Is your first query run success?

Comment: I'm sorry i put the line numbers before the wrong lines. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

$stmt = $conn->prepare statement may be return false.Please use given code for getting error in query.

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('your query')) {
    $stmt->bind_param(...);

}
else {
    printf("Error=: %s\n", $conn->error);
}
```